# How can I optimize the distance between 2 points (x,y,z) and two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I need to calculate the distance between each pixcel and each centroid.

Arguments:

- X (numpy array): PxD 1st set of data points (usually data points)
- C (numpy array): KxD 2nd set of data points (usually cluster centroids points)

Returns:

- dist: PxK numpy array position ij is the distance between the i-th point of the first set an the j-th point of the second set

```py
def distance(X, C):

    dist = numpy.empty((X.shape[0], C.shape[0]))

    for i,x in enumerate(X):
        for y,c in enumerate(C):
            dist[i][y] = euclidean_dist(x,c)

    return dist

def euclidean_dist(x, y):
    x1, y1, z1 = x
    x2, y2, z2 = y
    return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 + (z1-z2)**2)
```

Comment: Do you have an error? What is the issue with your code? Should it not be ```dist[i,y]```?

Comment: no, no errors. Just how can I work with matrix / array / numpy do to it faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can add scipy dependency, then this is already implemented in [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html). Otherwise we can use [numpy.broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [numpy.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

**Scipy Implemenation**

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance
distance.cdist(X, C, 'euclidean')
```

**Numpy Implementation**

```py
import numpy as np
np.linalg.norm(X[:,None,:] - C, axis=2)
```

**Performance**

```py
P = 100_000
K = 10_00
D = 3

X = np.random.randint(0,10, (P,D))
C = np.random.randint(0,10, (K,D))

%timeit distance.cdist(X, C, 'euclidean')
1.06 s ± 57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.linalg.norm(X[:,None,:] - C, axis=2)
15 s ± 2.18 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

We can see that for large sizes of `X` and `C` scipy implementation is way faster.